# Get current restart policy state (nodeRestartState) of AppServer using Jython

Tags: websphere, jython

I want to get the current restart policy of an AppServer (RUNNING, STOPPED or PREVIOUS) using Jython.

```
servers = AdminTask.listServers('[-serverType APPLICATION_SERVER]').splitlines()
for server in servers:
  print server
  print AdminConfig.showAttribute(server, "monitoringPolicy")
  break
```

This gave me an exception that the attribute is invalid:

> An exception occurred when executing the file "test.py". Information
>   about the exception: com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException:
>   WASX7080E: Invalid attributes for type "Server" -- "monitoringPolicy".

But I could get the attribute using `print AdminConfig.showall(server)`:

```
...
[monitoringPolicy [[autoRestart true]
[maximumStartupAttempts 3]
[nodeRestartState STOPPED]
[pingInterval 60]
[pingTimeout 300]]]
...
```

For me it looks like `monitoringPolicy` is the key of an array, so that it should be possible to get the restart state with

```
policy = AdminConfig.showAttribute(server, "monitoringPolicy")
restartState = policy["restartState"] # Should be "STOPPED"
```

Where is the problem?

### Edit

After taking a deeper look in the list output, I saw that I missed a top level property `processDefinitions`, which is the parent of `monitoringPolicy`.

```
pd = AdminConfig.showAttribute(server, "processDefinitions")
print pd
```

This prints:

```
[(cells/CnxCell/nodes/CnxNode01/servers/UtilCluster_server1|server.xml#JavaProcessDef_1578492353152)]
```

But I'm not able to get any of the child propertys from this object:

```
# TypeError: sequence subscript must be integer or slice
print pd["monitoringPolicy"]

# AttributeError: 'string' object has no attribute 'monitoringPolicy'
print pd.monitoringPolicy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MonitoringPolicy has his own type. This prints the server and the state, so 'RUNNING', 'STOPPED'

```
servers = AdminTask.listServers('[-serverType APPLICATION_SERVER]').splitlines()
for server in servers:
    print(server)
    mpol = AdminConfig.list("MonitoringPolicy", server)
    print(AdminConfig.showAttribute(mpol, 'nodeRestartState'))
```